# GLSL alpha test optimized out on NVIDIA

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia, alpha, fragment-shader

I have a small fragment shader on glsl, that is used when I want to render shadow texture. To have the desired shadow from textures with alpha channel (like leaves), alpha test is used.

```
#version 130
in lowp vec2 UV; //comes from vertex shader, works fine

uniform sampler2D DiffuseTextureSampler; //ok, alpha channel IS present in passed texture

void main(){
    lowp vec4 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture( DiffuseTextureSampler, UV ).rgba;
    if(MaterialDiffuseColor.a < 0.5)
    {
        discard;
    }
    //no color output is required at this stage
}
```

The following shader works fine on Intel cards (HD 520 && HD Graphics 3000), but on NVIDIA (420M and GTX 660, on Win7 and Linux Mint 17.3 respectively, using the latest drivers, 37x.xx something...) the alpha test does not work. Shader does compile without any errors, so it seems that NVIDIA optimizer is doing weird stuff.

I've copy-pasted parts of 'fullbright' shader to the 'shadow' shader, and got to this odd result, that does work as intended, though a lot of useless stuff (for shadow rendering) is done.

```
#version 130
in lowp vec2 UV;
in lowp float fade;

out lowp vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D DiffuseTextureSampler;
uniform bool overlayBool;
uniform lowp float translucencyAlpha;
uniform lowp float useImageAlpha;

void main(){
    lowp vec4 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture( DiffuseTextureSampler, UV ).rgba;
    //notice the added OR :/
    if(MaterialDiffuseColor.a < 0.5 || overlayBool)
    {
        discard;
    }
    //next line is meaningless
    color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, min(translucencyAlpha * useImageAlpha, fade));
}
```

If I remove any uniform, or change something (like, replace the min function with some arithmetic, save the declaration of uniform variable but do not use it etc), the alpha test breaks again.
  Just outputting the color does not work (ie color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); has no effect).

I tried using the

```
#pragma optimize (off)
```

but it did not help.

By the way, when alpha test is broken, the expression "MaterialDiffuseColor.a == 0.0" is true.

Sorry, if it is a dumb question, but what causes such behaviour on NVIDIA cards and what can I do to avoid it? Thank you.

Comment: What is your texture setup? Additionally: You know, that precision qualifiers have no effect in desktop OpenGL?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is a texture setup. I use 32bit 256x178 png image, if it matters. I remember, that I used precision qualifiers because I had issues with shader compiling on Intel gpu. I dont think the texture is the issue, as with the same texture different shaders (in the post) might work or not.

Comment: can you include your glTexImage2D() call so we know how your texture is setup?

Comment: I use gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());    where image is a class from SFML library.